# Windows 10 - Automatically focus windows on virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I really love the new virtual desktops of Windows 10, but everytime I switch to a virtual desktop, I have to press ALT+TAB to focus the *only* window on that desktop.

That kind of kills the feature, because if I have to press ALT+TAB *anyway* then I could just use one desktop.

So is there an autofocus option for Windows 10 virtual desktops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the behavior is as follows:

- When there is no window focused on the current desktop, then there will be no window focused on other desktops as well.
- When there is a window focused on the current desktop, then other windows will also be focused on other desktops, when you switch to the desktops.

That is a really strange behavior.

**EDIT**

According to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/virtual-desktop-loses-active-application-focus/6f699d0b-d961-4cfa-a9b8-9bd25963b14e?auth=1) it is a bug. Restarting the process explorer.exe returns the focus.

1. Kill the process in the taskmanager.
2. Keep the taskmanager open and click on File->Execute new task.
3. Type "explorer.exe" and run it.

These are free translations of the german version, but you should understand how to do it. The process does not restart itself, so it is important to keep the taskmanager open.

This is really annoying and I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: As a Win32 programmer, this makes perfect sense to me :)

Comment: Why? Can you tell me more about it? Because in this case I would expect a different behavior.

Comment: Wow thanks!  I can't believe restarting explorer.exe actually works, but it does!   Note that the instructions aren't quite right - in Windows 10 task manager, you have to scroll down to the "Windows processes" category, then to "Windows Explorer", then click "Restart."

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work today.